# Dimensional Modeling - Drilling Across with Role-Playing Dimensions

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I'm in the process of developing a dimensional model for a sales data mart. Currently, I have fact tables for invoices, credits, and rebates, amongst other things.

Where I'm struggling is that I need multiple date dimensions for each fact table, but I also need to be able to drill across the fact tables by some of these dates. As an example, I may want to look at all invoiced sales and credits for a customer during a particular year. Obviously, `FactCredits` doesn't have a key to `DimInvoicedDate`, and `FactInvoices` doesn't have a key to `DimCreditDate`.

The other dates contained in these fact tables are usually used to measure performance within the fact table. For example, `FactInvoices` has a key to `DimOrderReceivedDate` so that we can do metrics on order-to-invoice times, and the rebates and credits have a similar structure.

Do I create a single conformed date dimension, something like `DimTransactionDate` so that I can drill across the tables, or is there a more elegant way to handle this? For the most part, this should work, as the actual date of each transaction is the only dimension that would be drilled across (commonly). I've been using Kimball as a guide, but I can't find anything on the intersection of drilling across and role-playing dimensions.

Finally, if it helps, the data mart is primarily going to be consumed by users in Excel (Power Query) and Power BI. Ideally, users won't have to define the date relationships themselves, but they can if necessary.

Comment: A few observations: Any more than one date dimension is confusing to end users. Multiple date dimensions can often simply be boiled down to useful metrics such as "number of days to pay an invoice". Be guided on what the actual user requirement is. Remember that there are really two different types of reports: operational (detailed lists with dates and stuff) and "management" - historical aggregates often at a monthly level. "Drilling across" is a BI tool dependent function and since you are using Power BI, you need to conform to it's requirements (star schema, ideally one way filtering)